# django models - how can i create abstract methods

Tags: python, django, django-models, abstract-class, abstract-methods

In django abstract classes seem to be posibble by using:

```
class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

However I do not see how to declare abstract methods/functions within these classes that do not contain 
any logic like e.g.

```
class AbstractClass(models.Model):

    def abstractFunction():

    class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

The library abc repectively the notation @abstractmethod doesnt seem to applicable here, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I understand, you're correct. Meta: abstract=True in Django models is there to make sure Django doesn't create database tables for the model. It predates Pythons ABC, which might explain the naming/functional confusion.

[Inheriting from both ABC and django.db.models.Model raises metaclass exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085658/inheriting-from-both-abc-and-django-db-models-model-raises-metaclass-exception)

However, a quick search gave me this. Don't know if it breaks anything.
https://gist.github.com/gavinwahl/7778717

I do like how ABC raises an exception at class instantiation, so it would be pretty neat. Let me know if you find it useful.

Comment: thx @Johan Schiff, this is just the missing part of the puzzle. https://gist.github.com/gavinwahl/7778717 shows pretty well the use of abc in django.